# Nuxt3 nuxt loading indicator doesn't wait for page load for nested routes

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I added a `<NuxtLoadingIndicator />` to my layout. This works correctly for my routes. This also works when I go from a parent to a child route.

For example: from route `/user` to `/user/dashboard`.

However, when I go from a different route to a nested route, the timing of nuxt loading indicator fails. It completes before the page is loaded.

For example: from route `/key` to `/user/dashboard`.

All routes use the same layout and I use `router.push({path: '/user/dashboard'})` to go the route.

It looks like it happens, because the nuxt loading indicator looks for the "page:finish" event here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/blob/2fbc73b3a3965cfa32e99e74f639ff7f66e5397e/packages/nuxt/src/app/components/nuxt-loading-indicator.ts#L34

This event is fired when the parent and the child page load. How do I make sure the loading indicator only finishes after the child route is fully loaded?

Comment: What if you start using Nuxt's build-in `return navigateTo(route)`? I quickly tried here and it looks like switching between the two routes correctly - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-wjdzwy